# How to target localized button with RSpec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec2

I am using RSpec and Capybara for Ruby on Rails testing.

My Rails app is localized for a number of different languages (English, German, etc.).

For example, I would like Capybara to submit a form but obviously can't use its value to select it because the value changes depending on the language that has been chosen.

This won't work in my case:

```
click_button("Create my account")
```

Is there any way to simply select the first `input[type="submit"]` element on the page with Capybara?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: BTW: Using an ID is the way to go... But, normally testing functionality of clicking a button should not be affected by different localization. I always create tests against the default locale label... 'en' in my case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assign an id to the button and click it

```
click_button("button_id")
```

Source: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this solution.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say:

```
find('input[type="submit"]').first.click
```

but give it a class or an id, it's much safer.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get this to work though and ended up using an id.

Comment: @Tintin81 the working version is actually `find('input[type="submit"]').click` or alternatively using the same approach as above `all('input[type="submit"]').first.click`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
first('input[type="submit"]').click
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also narrow down @apneadiving's answer using css selectors:

find("#my_form input[type='submit']").click

That way you don't have to modify the HTML to match your tests.